# how to create bookmark in word using powershell

Tags: powershell, bookmarks

I have to create bookmark in the word document, but don't understand how to set define a range

```
$Word = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$Selection.Style =$Title
$Selection.TypeText($someText2)
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$doc.Bookmarks.Add($bN,???)"
```

I want to add some text to my document and then make this  text as bookmark.
What is the best way to do it?
Thank you/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are attempting to do, but this may work for what you are attempting to do:

```
$someText2 = "Some text to add"

#Open Active Word Document    
$Word = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
$Selection.Style = "Title"
$selection.TypeText("This is the Title")
$Selection.TypeParagraph()

#Add the bookmark to the Selection
$Selection.Bookmarks.Add("Bookmark1")
#Load the bookmark from the Selection
$bookmark = $Selection.Bookmarks._NewEnum | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Bookmark1"}
#add the text to the selection
$Selection.TypeText($someText2)
#set the end of the bookmark to the length of the added text
$bookmark.End = $bookmark.End + $someText2.Length
```

UPD

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Selection.TypeText($someText)
$Selection.TypeParagraph()

$Word = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Selection.Bookmarks.Add($bN)
$bookmark = $Selection.Bookmarks._NewEnum | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $bN}
$Selection.TypeText($someText2)
$bookmark.End = $bookmark.End + $someText2.Length
```

Comment: Thank you, as a result i receive a word document with correct bookmark. but additionally I get  this error: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.String'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more insight to your source script?

Comment: Thank you for your time. It's first part of the script: "$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Selection.TypeText($someText)
$Selection.TypeParagraph()
" and second: "$Word = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Selection.Bookmarks.Add($bN)
$bookmark = $Selection.Bookmarks._NewEnum | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $bN}
$Selection.TypeText($someText2)
$bookmark.End = $bookmark.End + $someText2.Length
"

Comment: I changed $Selection.Bookmarks.Add($bN)
$bookmark = $Selection.Bookmarks._NewEnum | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $bN} to $bookmark = $Selection.Bookmarks.Add($bN) and everything working cool. Thank you one more time!!!